# How to find WLST python version

Tags: python, wlst

In Weblogic how to find WLST python version. Its known that WLST is made up by python.

And Python 2 and Python 3 is different from one another Architecture wise and bit wise. Python 2 available for 64 bit considering Windows `OS`. Python 3 is still 32-bit as far I know. Python is well known simplest Higher Level Language that is widely used in many Industry, but classified like version 2 and 3.

When I work in WLST I wonder what would be the Python version it is made up of.

When Weblogic version differs does it differ. However it so, how to find out, is there a specific command or function for it while operating in `WLST shell`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will print the Python version used by WLST :

> print (sys.version)

Comment: Unfortunately I am connected from Home, dispersed & don't have Weblogic. Each `uname` says something different for each `UNIX` based box, so could you please put front what does it prints so for your `Weblogic App Server` and also mention your App Server version.

Comment: `wls:/offline> print (version)  
WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2.0  
  
wls:/offline>  
wls:/offline>  
wls:/offline> print sys.version  
2.2.1  
wls:/offline>`